# ssh to localhost not working, remote ssh works

Tags: ssh, sles

I have strange issue going on - I have 2 VM's as node01 and node02 running on a Windows host

- ssh from node01 to node02 works
- ssh from Host to node01 and node02 works
- ssh from node02 to node01 works

now when I do `ssh root@localhost` it does not work.

## SLES Version info:

```
cat /etc/issue

Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l).
```

## ssh verbose output:

```
node01:~/Desktop # ssh -vvv root@localhost
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Network is unreachable
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Network is unreachable
```

## contents from /etc/hosts:

```
# IP-Address  Full-Qualified-Hostname  Short-Hostname
#

127.0.0.1       localhost

# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0         ipv6-localnet

ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts
192.168.142.101 node01.mydomain.local node01
192.168.142.102 node02.mydomain.local node02
```

## enabled properties from :/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
(rest of the lines are comments)
```

## node01:~/Desktop # ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:2B:49:04  
          inet addr:192.168.142.101  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe2b:4904/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:416 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:50391 (49.2 Kb)  TX bytes:33156 (32.3 Kb)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          LOOPBACK  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

## node01:~/Desktop # iptables --list

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

## node01:~/Desktop # netstat -lnt

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3260            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::3260                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

## Successfull connectivity from VM Host to VM Guest (node01)

```
[2016-12-11 17:49.17]  ~
[VM Host] > ssh -v root@192.168.142.101
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.142.101 [192.168.142.101] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.142.101:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:n01c4dhTM/gzY4/vSmDpR59FysetbFVG3kcRNXZFycw
debug1: Host '192.168.142.101' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/known_hosts:149
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent refused operation
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.142.101 ([192.168.142.101]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Last login: Sun Dec 11 20:48:45 2016 from 192.168.142.1
```

Comment: No `ListenAddress` specified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Comment: It may be helpful if you provided the output of `sudo ifconfig -a` and `sudo iptables -l` and `netstat -lnt` from the broken box, as well as the SSH commands you have used to successfully connect from another machine.

Comment: `ssh 127.0.0.1` works? Seems like misconifigured IPv6

Answer (score 3):

As your `ifconfig` output shows:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          LOOPBACK  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

...you seem to be missing the IP addresses that belong on `lo`. `lo` normally must have two IP addresses: 127.0.0.1/8, and ::1/128. The system startup scripts usually ensure that this is the case and your system would be considered broken if it doesn't do it.

You can fix it temporarily with these commands:

```
ip link set lo up
ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
ip addr add ::1/128 dev lo
```

but this won't save it for next time. For next time, you'll want to fix whatever's wrong. I don't know how that's done with your distribution, but if it were a Debian-like distribution then you could ensure that this appears in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: ok localhost loop back ip is not available, but even ssh using the IP or hostname still doen't work as in "ssh -v root@node01" gives me following output                                                                                                                /**node01:~/Desktop # ssh -v root@node01
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to node01 [192.168.142.101] port 22.
**/

Comment: @user4488573 Well I don't know but I wouldn't trust much IP connectivity to work on a system with broken localhost because localhost is kind of fundamental. Please fix that first before diagnosing any further.

Comment: I just reinstalled and this time the localhost IP came back and worked as normal. The older installation I tried to fix it but it did not work at all, so I trashed those VM's - thanks much.

Comment: try restarting the sshd service using  "sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart"